# How to remove items from array in javaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to remove specific items in array.Below is the array(Status)

```js
    0: {id: 5, description: "Assign"}
    1: {id: 8, description: "Business Case Review"}
    2: {id: 4, description: "Cancelled"}
    3: {id: 3, description: "Closed"}
    4: {id: 6, description: "Confirm"}
    5: {id: 7, description: "Not Started"}
    6: {id: 2, description: "On Hold"}
    7: {id: 18, description: "Pending CEMT Approval"}
    8: {id: 9, description: "Problem Statement Review"}
    9: {id: 10, description: "Review Board"}
    Code:
    
    Status.forEach(function (ap)
     {if ( ap.description != 'Not Started'
     && ap.description !='Review Board' 
     && ap.description != 'Cancelled'
     && ap.description !='Business Case Review'
     && ap.description !='Problem Statement Review'
     ) 
     {
       Status.splice(Status.indexOf(ap), 1);
      }
      })
```

**Output**:

> Business Case Review, Cancelled, Confirm, Not Started, Pending
> CEMT Approval, Problem Statement Review, Review Board. Desired
> Output:Business Case Review, Cancelled, Not Started, Problem Statement
> Review,Review Board.

when checking if condition after deleting item in the array below item will move to previous item index since the current item wont come for validation this is causing the problem. Can some one assist in this regards.

Comment: use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Maybe you can use a Map instear of an Array...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the filter method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),

Example :

```
array.filter(element => element.description !== "Business Case Review")
```

will return you a new array with all the objects except the one which has "Business Case Review" as description

Answer (score -1):

Define your filters as an array and then filter your array with that filter as follows:

```
const filters = [
'Not Started',
'Review Board', 
'Cancelled',
'Business Case Review',
'Problem Statement Review'
]

var filteredResult = yourArray.filter(element => !filters.includes(element.description))
```

Comment: it is working when i am executing as a separate program, but when i added to my project code and doing grunt build it is failing, can you please help me why it is failing grunt build.

Comment: >> Uglifying source .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js failed.
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected token: operator (>).
Line 6152 in .tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js
 Used --force, continuing.
Warning: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined Used --force, continuing.

Comment: @Rajitrmp try to run `grunt --verbose --stack --debug`
what does it say?

Answer (score -1):

```
let Status = [
          {id: 5, description: "Assign"},
          {id: 8, description: "Business Case Review"},
          {id: 4, description: "Cancelled"},
          {id: 3, description: "Closed"},
          {id: 6, description: "Confirm"},
          {id: 7, description: "Not Started"},
          {id: 2, description: "On Hold"},
          {id: 18, description: "Pending CEMT Approval"},
          {id: 9, description: "Problem Statement Review"},
          {id: 10, description: "Review Board"}
        ];
        let listOfRemoveItemIndex = []
        for (let index = 0; index < Status.length; index++) {
          const ap = Status[index];
          if ( ap.description != 'Not Started' && ap.description !='Review Board' && ap.description != 'Cancelled' && ap.description !='Business Case Review' && ap.description !='Problem Statement Review') 
                {
                  listOfRemoveItemIndex.push(index);

                }
        }
        listOfRemoveItemIndex.forEach((index) => {
          Status.splice(index, 1);
        });
        console.log(" Status : ", Status);
```